# could not be resolved to an installable set of packages

Tags: php, slim, zend-mail

I tried to install package `zendmail` but I got the error below

```
k15@k15-Aspire-4732Z:~/Documents/strawberry$ composer require zendframework/zend-mail
Using version ^2.8 for zendframework/zend-mail
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - phpunit/php-code-coverage 4.0.8 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/php-code-coverage 4.0.8 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/php-code-coverage 4.0.8 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for phpunit/php-code-coverage (locked at 4.0.8) -> satisfiable by phpunit/php-code-coverage[4.0.8].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
Linter
Severity  Provider  Description Line
```

I don't know what I should do with the error. Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install the DOM capabilities for php (as shown by the error message `phpunit/php-code-coverage 4.0.8 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.`)

This looks (from the output of extensions) like a Debian based machine. `apt install php7.0-xml` should allow you to continue.

Answer (score -1):

In Zend framework 2, by default mail package will be there, you can just use this piece of code.,

```
use Zend\Mail;

$mail = new Mail\Message();
$mail->setBody('This is the text of the email.');
$mail->setFrom('Freeaqingme@example.org', 'Sender\'s name');
$mail->addTo('Matthew@example.com', 'Name o. recipient');
$mail->setSubject('TestSubject');

$transport = new Mail\Transport\Sendmail();
$transport->send($mail);
```

for reference, you can visit this page, https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.mail.introduction.html